# image line detection for a grayscale image .. not working

Tags: python, image-processing, straight-line-detection

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGvyj.png)

This is a 3000x3000 greyscale image, and I would like to get the coordinates of the diagonal components in the image.

I tried Hough transform and pylsd (line segment detection), but both of them don't work as I hoped. Here are some unsatisfactory outcomes:

[result with too many junks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkEyK.png)

I would like to have a maximum amount of true diagonals with minimum number of junks by using a simple parameter such as the length above which a cluster can be labeled as a line. Any suggestions or tips will be appreciated.

Either Python or R is preferred (not matlab)

Comment: I also wanted to add a result that is too simple (one straight diagonal), but my reputation level doesn't allow me ;(